# CartThrob / SagePay sudden error 5006 after server move?

Tags: cartthrob, payment-gateway, sagepay

After a recent server move and a new dedicated IP address configuration the site no longer works with SagePay (offsite server), we now get the following error(s) after entering payment details at SagePay:

HTTP Status Code:   500
HTTP Status Message:    The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.

Error Code :    5006
Error Description : Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.

The IP address is valid within SagePay and I have checked that the return path from the checkout_form is correct, both are ok.

I'm not sure why this has stopped working, any help please? Thanks.

EE v2.7.3 and CT v2.5 - I have tried the new SagePay code provided by Vector Media Group but the same errors are issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making sure all your paths are correct in the server move, especially as listed here: `themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib/extload.php`. That's usually the issue in this kind of situation.

Comment: Nice one Matt, thanks for that, it was indeed the paths!